# How to find a parameter value using input in shell script

Tags: shell

I have a scenario to create a generic script that will use the input value and get actual value from config file and use it for further logic.

```
pattern.config file
TYPE1_PATH=/path/to/type1
TYPE2_PATH=/path/to/type2
```

I want to run my script `./run.sh TYPE1` and do like `PATTERN=$1"_PATH"` now `$PATTERN=TYPE1_PATH`. But not sure how to get the value of `$TYPE1_PATH` from config

Answer (score 1):

This is [Bash FAQ 006](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006).

Specifically [Evaluating indirect/reference variables](http://mywiki.wooledge.org/BashFAQ/006#Evaluating_indirect.2Freference_variables):

```
# Bash
realvariable=contents
ref=realvariable
echo "${!ref}"   # prints the contents of the real variable

# ksh93 / mksh / Bash 4.3
realvariable=contents
typeset -n ref=realvariable
echo "${!ref} = $ref"      # prints the name and contents of the real variable

# zsh
realvariable=contents
ref=realvariable
echo ${(P)ref}   # prints the contents of the real variable
```

Comment: Thank you Etan, that is exactly what i needed.